# Good search term in Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Using Rails 3.2, Sphinx Search and Thinking Sphinx gem. I have tried wrapping `%` and `*`, and wildcard, in the keywords in my controller, but can't achieve what I want:

Keywords to search:

- world trade
- worldtrade
- worl trade
- trade world
- trad worl

Expected matched search results:

- World Trade Center

How should I format the keywords in my controller so that I get the expected search result with the different keywords as shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For Sphinx, the wildcard character is * - so there's no point using %.
- If you want every query to have wildcards added to it, use :star => true in your Thinking Sphinx search call.
- If you want to match on parts of words, you need to enable either [min_prefix_len or min_infix_len](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/advanced_config.html). The default is 0 (disabled), but given your examples, perhaps 4 is a good setting? The lower it is, the larger your index files get (and so searches may get slower as well), so perhaps don't set it to 1 unless you need to.
- All of the above points won't make 'worldtrade' match, because you're providing one long word instead of two separate ones. You could look into adding a [wordforms](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms) file to your Sphinx configuration, but that may be overkill in this case, as you'd want to cover each specific case.